# & Operator in C++ and how it impacts performance of code

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

These two functions are nearly identical, with the only difference being the initialization in the for-loop. Why does the latter result in Time Limit Exceeded errors for my program?

Solution 1:

```
    bool validPath(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges, int source, int destination) {    
        vector<bool> visited(n, false);
        queue<int> queue; 
        queue.push(source);
        visited[source] = true; 

        while(queue.size() > 0) {
            int currentVertex = queue.front();
            if(currentVertex == destination) return true; 
            queue.pop();
            for(vector<int>& edge : edges) {
                if(currentVertex == edge[0] && !visited[edge[1]]) {
                    visited[edge[1]] = true; 
                    queue.push(edge[1]);
                    
                } else if(currentVertex == edge[1] && !visited[edge[0]]) {
                    visited[edge[0]] = true; 
                    queue.push(edge[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        return false; 
    } 
};
```

Solution 2:

```
    bool validPath(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges, int source, int destination) {    
        vector<bool> visited(n, false);
        queue<int> queue; 
        queue.push(source);
        visited[source] = true; 

        while(queue.size() > 0) {
            int currentVertex = queue.front();
            if(currentVertex == destination) return true; 
            queue.pop();
            for(vector<int> edge : edges) {
                if(currentVertex == edge[0] && !visited[edge[1]]) {
                    visited[edge[1]] = true; 
                    queue.push(edge[1]);
                    
                } else if(currentVertex == edge[1] && !visited[edge[0]]) {
                    visited[edge[0]] = true; 
                    queue.push(edge[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        return false; 
    } 
};
```

The only difference is:

```
for(vector<int>& edge : edges)
```

versus

```
for(vector<int> edge : edges)
```

Comment: Using `vector` for edges of a graph is unusual, because you can use simpler types like `pair` or `struct`. If you use these, copying is not a problem anymore.

Comment: `&` in a type is not an operator, it denotes a reference type.

Comment: By using a reference you will avoid copying the edge vector. For simplicity assume for now a reference is a pointer to something that can never be a nullptr it has to refer to a valid object.

Comment: The `operator&` is very efficient,  The compiler can usually emit one instruction that performs the bit-wise AND of two numbers.  Depends on the processor.  The compiler may have to emit some overhead instructions, for example, loading from memory into a register.

Comment: The `operator&` is very efficient at returning the address or location of a variable.  Compilers either emit instructions to load the register with a value or the address may be stored in memory and compiler fetches the address value from memory.

Answer (score -1):

`for(vector<int> edge : edges)` will copy! each vector of edges which takes time.

`for(vector<int>& edge : edges)` creates a reference to the given vector without any copy action needed.

Quite clear that a full copy of a vector will always be slower.

BTW: On a first view you can define some of your variables as `const` which may result in better optimization. Sometimes the compiler "sees" that you did not modify the vars and optimizes as if the variable is already const defined.